# How do I replace string containing square brackets

Tags: regex, bash, sed

Help me, please.
There is a file with such strings:

```
<b>[source:1:2:3]</b>
<b>[source:2:3:1]</b>
<b>[source:3:1:2]</b>
<b>[source:1:3:2]</b>
```

I only need to convert one line from this file. The result should be such a file:

```
<b>[source:1:2:3]</b>
<b>[source:2:3:1]</b>
<b>[result:3:1:2]</b>
<b>[source:1:3:2]</b>
```

Broke my head trying to escape [ with sed :(
Probably should be something like this:

```
cat test.txt |sed "s,<b>\[source:3:1:2\]</b>,<b>\[result:3:1:2\]</b>,g"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** To look for specific string and then change line use following.

```
awk -v old_string="source" -v new_string="result" '/<b>\[source:3:1:2\]<\/b>/{sub(old_string,new_string)} 1' Input_file
```

OR to save results into same Input_file then try following.

```
awk -v old_string="source" -v new_string="result" '/<b>\[source:3:1:2\]<\/b>/{sub(old_string,new_string)} 1' Input_file > temp && mv temp Input_file
```

---

---

If you are ok with `awk` then try following.

```
awk 'FNR==3{sub(/source/,"result")} 1'  Input_file
```

OR if you want to have variables of current and new values in `awk` code then try following.

```
awk -v old_string="source" -v new_string="result" 'FNR==3{sub(old_string,new_string)} 1' Input_file
```

Comment: Unfortunately, there may be more lines in the file and the numbers in them may be different. I just need to find the original line and replace one word in it.

Comment: @Evgeny, sorry I didn't get it, how we are going to get on which line we should do substitutions? could you please clarify on same? Is this number of a string we need to look for?

Comment: Strings and numbers in them are unique. I need to find one string with specific values in the row. In this example it is: <b>[source:3:1:2]</b>

Comment: @Evgeny, Could you please try my EDIT code now and lemme know?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot!